# predicting maximum output along with corresponding feature values through ML models

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, constrained-optimization

I'm trying to optimize efficiency of a system, I've trained and tested multiple ML models such as polynomial regression, RFR, XGBOOST and MLP.
my initial thought was to use bayesian optimization to maximize objective function (I tried using my linear regression model as objective function, idk if it was the right choice, it didn't work tho). now, after some surfing on web, I've come upon genetic algorithm but I don't know if it'll work as well
is it possible to find the corresponding feature values which give maximum output form these predictive models? if so, how

Comment: I think this likely depends on which of those models you end up selecting, and potentially on more information about it (hyperparameters, performance).

Comment: What didn't work about linear regression? That one should be easiest, although perhaps the answer is too degenerate to be useful?

Comment: @BenReiniger it does depend upon which model i choose, I was trying to get a hang of it by choosing linear regression model to find the optimum value of output, my feature values that affect the output are constrained to a specific range, my aim was to find the maximum output possible from a set of feature values with in that range, a gentle push in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027690/finding-model-predictor-values-that-maximize-the-outcome/40028827#40028827

Comment: So that linked answer spells out what I meant about linear regression, and then works on the splines.  For tree ensembles, I provided [a partial answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77827945/10495893).  I think this question is too broad as is, because it depends on the model flavor.